# RabbitMQ clustering use case w/o HA

Tags: rabbitmq

this is a use case question on RabbitMQ clustering. In the past, I have clustered RabbitMQ to make queues highly available (HA). I understand you can cluster RabbitMQ nodes without making HA queues but why would you do that? From a message consumer's POV, clustering in itself buys you nothing unless the queues are made HA (or so I feel). What kind of use-cases can you cite for make a non-HA RabbitMQ cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By having more servers you can get more throughput, be able to accept more connected clients and so on. The non HA cluster is able to see resources in all nodes in the clusters, despite of where the resources were declared.